# how to add a user control from a dll(already referenced) to ui in design mode?

Tags: dll, user-controls, designmode

If i first add it to the toolbox, an exception will be thrown, saying the dll is already referenced.

and i hate to add it to ui programmatically.

any idea? i have to add it programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about removing previous reference and browsing to the dll ?

Comment: that's exactly what i end up did.

Answer (score 0):

firs add a new user control to your project
after coding has finished, then Build your project. so you'll see the your created control appears in the toolbox(at the top), then just drag & drop it on your form or any ui and if you want to load a control from a DLL just add a new tab in your tool box then right click on it and select "choose items..." and then in the .Net Framework Components tab click "browse" and navigate to your dll , and then open the dll file and confirm the choose items dialog and you see the user control is now ready for drag &  drop in your tool box :)

Comment: you didn't get my question.  the control is in dll, and it's already referenced by my project, how to make it show up in the toolbox window? if you choose browse to select the dll, then the ide will complain the dll is already referenced.